# getopts for more than 4 parser arguments

Tags: bash, getopts

I want to parse multiple arguments using `getopts` in a `bash` script using the code below.

```bash
while getopts b:B:m:M:T flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        b) rbmin=${OPTARG};;
        B) rbmax=${OPTARG};;
        m) mbmin=${OPTARG};;
        M) mbmax=${OPTARG};;
        T) sigType=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
echo $rbmin,$rbmax,$mbmin,$mbmax, $sigType
```

```bash
[amit@amitk]$ sh pass.sh -b 0.1 -B 0.3  -m 10 -M 11 -T sig 
0.1,0.3,10,11,
```

I don't know why I cannot pass more than four arguments. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `:` after `T` in the option string given to `getopts`.  This `:` would indicate that `-T` takes an option-argument.

Without the `:`, `-T` would be an option with no argument, and your invocation would leave `sig` as an operand at the end of the command line rather than as an option-argument.

```bash
while getopts b:B:m:M:T: flag
do
    case $flag in
        b) rbmin=$OPTARG        ;;
        B) rbmax=$OPTARG        ;;
        m) mbmin=$OPTARG        ;;
        M) mbmax=$OPTARG        ;;
        T) sigType=$OPTARG      ;;
        *) echo error >&2
           exit 1
    esac
done
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

echo "$rbmin,$rbmax,$mbmin,$mbmax, $sigType"

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        printf 'Other operands: %s\n' "$*"
fi
```

Testing:

```bash
$ sh script -b 0.1 -B 0.3  -m 10 -M 11 -T sig
0.1,0.3,10,11, sig
```

```bash
$ sh script -b 0.1 -B 0.3  -m 10 -M 11 -T sig hello bumblebee
0.1,0.3,10,11, sig
Other operands: hello bumblebee
```

Also note that if you run the script by using an explicit interpreter like `sh`, you may not be running the script with `bash`.  I only mention this because you mentioned "`bash` script" in the question.  In this instance, it's ok since the script does not *require* `bash`, but it would be better to use an executable file with the proper `#!`-line at the top.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda!,  It worked.

Comment: (about missing shebang), presumably we don't see the top of the OP's script. If we do see the top of the OP's script, we should point out that initialisation of those variables (even if only with `unset -v rbmin rbmax...`) is also missing.